# Sharelatex doesn't recognize my bibliography entries

Tags: bibtex, sharelatex

I'm using Sharelatex for my thesis, but I was using LaTeX with TeXnic center before. Sharelatex is not recognizing my bib entries. I just can cite the first twelve entries but from to the 13th to the last one, it says "undefined reference". I have no idea why! I'm using apastyle, I've tried uploading the file again, or manually typing the entries but nothing seems to work!

I've wasted a couple of hours now, trying to fix this issue with no success! Do you have any idea about why?

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliografia/referencias}
```

I have no special commands in my documents as you can see! I even tried changing the citation style!

Here is an example of an entry:

```
@book{epic237530,
editor = {R.K. Pachauri and L. Meyer},
title = {Climate Change 2014: Synthesis Report. Contribution of Working Groups I, II and III to the Fifth Assessment Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change},
author = {R. K. Pachauri and M. R. Allen and V. R. Barros and J. Broome and W. Cramer and R. Christ and J. A. Church and L. Clarke and Q. Dahe and P. Dasgupta and N. K. Dubash and O. Edenhofer and I. Elgizouli and C. B. Field and P. Forster and P. Friedlingstein and J. Fuglestvedt and L. Gomez-Echeverri and S. Hallegatte and G. Hegerl and M. Howden and K. Jiang and B. Jimenez Cisneroz and V. Kattsov and H. Lee and K. J. Mach and J. Marotzke and M. D. Mastrandrea and L. Meyer and J. Minx and Y. Mulugetta and K. O'Brien and M. Oppenheimer and J. J. Pereira and R. Pichs-Madruga and G.-K. Plattner and Hans-Otto P{\"o}rtner and S. B. Power and B. Preston and N. H. Ravindranath and A. Reisinger and K. Riahi and M. Rusticucci and R. Scholes and K. Seyboth and Y. Sokona and R. Stavins and T. F. Stocker and P. Tschakert and D. van Vuuren and J.-P. van Ypserle},
address = {Geneva, Switzerland},
publisher = {IPCC},
year = {2014},
pages = {151},
}
```

And I try to cite it using `\citep{epic237530}`, but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome again :)

Comment: My impression is that the long list of authors exceeds the buffer of BibTeX. Can you look in the `.blg` file? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I bet this is a compiled work. Are you citing a specific article/entry, or the book as a complete work?

Comment: How can I find that file? I'm using a template I just downloaded from the web...but I don't think it's because of the long list of authors, since it happens to me with all my entries...no only books, but articles, reports, everything, even if they only have a single author! I forgot to mention that I'm only trying to cite the book as a complete work with the instruction I listed before. Thanks

Comment: I can share the sharelatex link of my document with you so you can check the error!! Would that be helpful?

Comment: sharelatex has a link to "other log files". check the content of the blg-file.

Comment: Does your project on ShareLaTeX include a folder `Bibliografia` and does that folder include a file `referencias.bib`? Just a check on the obvious.... Have you tried putting the `.bib` file in the root of the project?

Comment: Hi cfr, yes, it includes that path. I've not tried to put it in the root of the project, I don't know how to do it, sorry but I'm new with sharelatex!!

Comment: I just found the link to "other log files", but it doesn't have the blg file. I checked another project that I have, and this one, it has the blg file; but my thesis one doesn't! I used an option to "see the full log file", and I checked it. This file seems to have like a description of my errors when compiling, but all it says about my citations is: "Package natbib Warning: Citation `CasulliCheng' on page 1 undefined on input li
ne 29."

Comment: @cfr I bet you have never seen the two comments above. Do you see any reasonable thing to do here? Right now, the question is completelyy unclear.

Comment: @Johannes_B Close as unclear, I guess. The reference in the last comment to 'my errors' is probably telling. Probably ShareLaTeX doesn't try to create the bibliography in that case. (Though I'd expect it to just stop compiling, but I don't use ShareLaTeX, so I'm not sure.) Since we don't know what those errors are. 2 years on, we'd best hope the OP found a solution elsewhere by now.

Comment: @cfr The *errors* made me suspicious as well. I voted too.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the ping, by the way. No, I'd never seen those comments. (At least, not that I recall.)